# Parsing MySQL TimeStamp to Javascript with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, angularjs, node.js

i am using nodejs to connet to mySql Db. using node is ma able to retrieve all tables . Node is used as a backend with express.

I have a route http://localhost:3000/getALL

when i consume this i get all the data in JSON format. but i am having issues converting mySql time to JS  object

```
[{"file_name":"150412-001070",
"date_time":"2015-07-21T13:11:55.000Z",
"polpospercent":68.95,"polnegpercent":31.05,
"Anger":6.58,
"Surprise":32.87,
"Sadness":32.87,
"Joy":4.59,
"Disgust":13.84,
"Fear":9.26,
"file_ts":"2014-04-26T22:03:00.000Z"}]
```

I need to convert file_ts to JS date and perform sort on it by Date.
This is also not sorted on angularjs ngTable.

Comment: I suggest having a look at sailsjs.

Comment: what's wrong with the built-in Date method? `new Date("2014-04-26T22:03:00.000Z")` do also note that you can sort such ISO strings as text since they all have leading zeros and most-significant digits first. lastly, it's better for more reasons than not to sort in msql, `order by file_ts`...

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com):

```
moment(date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ').format('MM-DD-YYYY [or whatever]');
```

Since it's ISO standard though, you should be able to just do:

```
moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY [or whatever]');
```

Comment: why use moment for an ISO date? i can see for something like "12-10-95", but for ISO?

Comment: Looked to me like OP wants to format it.  But you're right, `new Date(date)` works just fine too.